# Context value getting undefined inside nested Loop

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, feathersjs, feathers-hook

Below java-script code context value became undefined inside nested loop.but outside the nested loop the values is properly showing.

please help to show the context value inside the loop.

```
module.exports = function (options = {}) { 
  return async context => {
    const { data } = context;

     context.app.service('emplist').find({
        query: { empId: { $in: ["12321"] } },
        paginate: false,
    }).then(result => {

        console.log('firstname_Inside-->',context.data.firstname);

    }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
    });

        console.log('firstname_Outside-->',context.data.firstname);

    return context;
  };
};
```

OUTPUT:-

```
//here value is undefined
firstname_Inside-->undefined

//here value is properly showing
firstname_Outside-->sam
```

Comment: Outside value gets printed first right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `context.app.service('emplist').find()` call is asynchronous. And it affects the `context`. So the possible answer would be that `context.data` object is being cleaned up during `context.app.service('emplist').find()` work.